# How can I make sure that my clipboard is safe while browsing?

Tags: browser, clipboard, internet-security

Sometimes my browser is open and I copy-paste sensitive information in an other app. (or on a different tab in the browser).

- May a webpage in my browser peek into my clipboard and steal info?
- (If yes,) is there any solution to protect my clipboard? (I am particularly worried about hidden flash objects...)
- Does this issue depend on operating system I use? (I am using OSX 10.7, Windows 7 and occasionally Ubuntu)

Comment: Every operating system is different.  An application on Windows 7 requires specific approval from the user to access the clipboard.  OS X and Ubuntu work in similar ways.  If you are worried about this use the privacy mode in the browser and disable Flash.

Comment: @Ramhound: Hang on, so you are saying you know that Flash puts me into danger but other active content (such as javascript) do not, regardless of the browser?

Comment: There are browser specific solutions to disable Javascript on a case by case basis.  There are also limits what Java and Javascript can do, extending into another tab, is prevented by most browsers.  Any application you provide access to the clipboard can access it.  My suggestion to disable Java was based on the fact you are worried about hidden flash objects.